# Newbee Material Design Lite Align

Tags: css, material-design

I am trying to build a simple login page, similar to pintrest login. Where I have Facebook/Google+ and 2 textboxes for user/pass. A button, to authenticate the user. 
I tried using MDT card, but it always displays on the top right and not in the center of the browser. 
I wanted to know how that could be achieved. The other question was, when the user is authenticated, I wanted to display an error message, if the user was not found.
I have a snippet of code, which has few of the fields.

```
html>   
    <body>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
        <script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.2.1/material.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="material.min.css">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var button = document.createElement('button');
            var textNode = document.createTextNode('Click Me!');
            button.appendChild(textNode);
            button.className = 'mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect';
            componentHandler.upgradeElement(button);
            document.getElementById('container').appendChild(button);
        </script>
    <div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-color--grey-100">
    <main class="mdl-layout__content">
        <div class="mdl-card mdl-shadow--6dp">
            <div class="mdl-card__title mdl-color--primary mdl-color-text--white">
                <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">Login</h2>
            </div>
        <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
                <form action="#">
                    <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield">
                        <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="email" />
                        <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="email">Email</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield">
                        <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="password" id="userpass" />
                        <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="userpass">Password</label>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
                <button class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">Sign In </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you have two `<body>` tags?

Comment: Thanks Neil I will look into Flexbox, I have seen display: flex in Polymer, but not sure if MDL supports it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with MDL and your code could use some TLC, but I believe what you are looking for *(at least the easiest way)* is [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

More specifically, a flex grid system would be the most helpful. I'm not sure but I don't think MDL even has a grid system. Foundation and Bootstrap do both have flex grid systems you can use. *(I prefer Foundation's)* There are also many standalone grid frameworks you can pair with anything.

The nice thing about flex grids, and really flexbox in general, is that you can center virtually anything both horizontally and vertically.

Comment: Thanks @Neil Smith I will look into Flexbox, I have seen display: flex in Polymer, but not sure if MDL supports it.
Also, if I have to pick up a UI framework what would be easier Bootstrap or Foundations? I am trying to use Node/Express for Middleware/Server-side Dev.

Comment: I love Foundation! In my opinion its the most complete, easy to use, and powerful CSS Framework. It also has an easy to override style, very in-depth documentation, a great community, and include the Sass files if you want to customize it. It comes as a css and js (for the accordions and carousels etc) file so it should be fine on Node.